# How to execute a function in my javascript when someone opens console log in my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

So basically my req is to hide 2 fields username and password in a form from viewing it in console log. So what i am planning to do is to listen to event console log and when it executes i remove the values from username and password.
How can i do it? i am also using jquery in my page.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "console log"? Are you talking about the DevTools?

Comment: You could wrap the console.log to call a callback when ever its executed then call-down to the existing log. However what would stop them displaying the fields again using devtools?

Comment: What is this achieving? It certainly does not add any level of security and can be trivially bypassed.. The client is insecure by nature, therefore never expose a weakness and try and obscure it with javascript

Comment: @SinDeus Yes Developer tools

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, and you shouldn't try. Never expose sensitive data like passwords like this.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot hide these data, because javascript is client-side.

Despite of the advises you received, Facebook uses this system and expose in browser username and password by accessing https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=110 when you try to connect, along with all inputs from your form. This procedure is often used before submitting for different reasons: verify email if it is not duplicate, how many login attempts were...

As long as you have SSL connection the only user that can see username, email or password in console is the one who enters these sensitive data in the form so it is not a threat.